# opencv cv::mat not returning the same result

Tags: opencv

```
    int sizeOfChannel = (_width / 2) * (_height / 2);
    double* channel_gr = new double[sizeOfChannel];

  // filling the data into channel_gr....

    cv::Mat my( _width/2, _height/2, CV_32F,channel_gr);        
    cv::Mat src(_width/2, _height/2, CV_32F);
    for (int i = 0; i < (_width/2) * (_height/2); ++i)
    {
        src.at<float>(i) = channel_gr[i];       
    }
    cv::imshow("src",src);
    cv::imshow("my",my);
    cv::waitKey(0);
```

I'm wondering why i'm not getting the same image in my and src imshow

 update:
I have changed my array into double* still same result;
I think it is something to do with steps?

my image output
[image]

src image output
[image]

Comment: Maybe because channel_gr is an int array, not a float array.

Comment: how about using CV_64F? or the issue with using int array may be?

Comment: @ha9u63ar exception is thrown

Comment: what's this _width/2 thing ? also note, that it's Mat(row,cols,type), you got it in reverse. (there's a lot of potholes on the way, - congrats, you've hit them all !)

Comment: @berak int sizeOfChannel = (_width / 2) * (_height / 2); takes the original image and cut it into because I need one one channel from the Bayer Pattern. i'm have no problem with cv::Mat(rows,cols,type); it is the ctor with the input array which is my problem. something like Mat(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type, void* data, const size_t* steps=0);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one works for me:

```
int halfWidth = _width/2;
int halfHeight = _height/2;
int sizeOfChannel = halfHeight*halfWidth;

// ******************************* //
// you use CV_321FC1 later so it is single precision float
float* channel_gr = new float[sizeOfChannel];

// filling the data into channel_gr....
for(int i=0; i<sizeOfChannel; ++i) channel_gr[i] = i/(float)sizeOfChannel;



// ******************************* //
// changed row/col ordering, but this shouldnt be important
cv::Mat my( halfHeight , halfWidth , CV_32FC1,channel_gr);        
cv::Mat src(halfHeight , halfWidth, CV_32FC1);


// ******************************* //
// changed from 1D indexing to 2D indexing
for(int y=0; y<src.rows; ++y)
for(int x=0; x<src.cols; ++x)
{
    int arrayPos = y*halfWidth + x;
    // you have a 2D mat so access it in 2D
    src.at<float>(y,x) = channel_gr[arrayPos ];       
}


cv::imshow("src",src);
cv::imshow("my",my);

// check for differences
cv::imshow("diff1 > 0",src-my > 0);
cv::imshow("diff2 > 0",my-src > 0);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Comment: thanks, you think the problem is just my channel_gr? which needs to be float and not double?

Comment: possible. but if src isnt continuous you would have to consider `.step` value to access the right pixel location if you use 1D indexing!

Comment: have marked for each region what kind of things have been changed. the most important part will be the float-instead-of-double array. row-vs-col might or might not be important. 1D-vs-2D indexing should only be a problem if the matrix isnt continuous, but probably should be cared about for stable code. E.g. if you use IPP support I guess that matrices wont be continuous all the time.

Answer (score 1):

'my' is array of floats but you give it pointer to arrays of double. There no way it can get data from this array properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the constructor version that you are using is

```
 Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, const Scalar& s)
```

This is from OpenCV docs. Seems like you are using `float` for `src` and assigning from `channel_gr` (declared as `double`). Isn't that some form of precision loss?

Comment: yes it's a percision loss which I', aware of. and it is ok